# NSLog is unavailable

Tags: swift, nslog

I have following function:

```
func myNSLog(_ givenFormat: String, _ args: CVarArg..., _ function:String = #function) {
        let format = "\(function): \(givenFormat)"
        NSLog(format, args)
```

Which results in the following error:

> 'NSLog' has been explicitly marked unavailable here (Foundation.NSLog)

Within the documentation is it explicit listed as available. What do I miss?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similar as in C, you cannot pass a variable argument list directly
to another function. You have to create a `CVaListPointer` (the Swift
equivalent of `va_list`) and pass that to the `NSLogv` variant:

```
func myNSLog(_ givenFormat: String, _ args: CVarArg..., _ function:String = #function) {
    let format = "\(function): \(givenFormat)"
    withVaList(args) { NSLogv(format, $0) }
}
```

(Swift 3 code.)