# Log message variadic params from ObjC to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How can I rewrite this code for Swift 3 or 4?

```
+ (void)logMessage:(NSString *)format, ... {

        va_list args;
        va_start(args, format);
        NSLogv([NSString stringWithFormat:@"<MYCLASS> %@", format], args);
        va_end(args);
}
```

thanks a lot

**EDIT 06/15**
My solution:

```
func logMessage(_ args: Any...) {

    print("<MYCLASS> \(args.map { "\($0)" }.joined(separator: " "))") 
}
```

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993693/nslog-is-unavailable

Comment: I tried but doesn't work, thanks to reply

Comment: What did you try, and how does it not work? Please update the question accordingly.