# how to transfer objective-c language (`va_list`,`va_start `,`va_end ` ) to swift language？

Tags: objective-c, swift

This is my codes. they are objective-c language:

```
- (void)objcMethod:(NSString *)format, ...
{
va_list args;

va_start(args, format);

NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args];
NSLog(@"%@", msg);

va_end(args);

va_start(args, format);

va_end(args);
}
```

how to transfer objective-c language (`va_list`,`va_start`,`va_end` ) to swift language？

I also need to call this swift method in objective-c xxx.m file.

Need help. thanks!

======================================================================

update:

I tried MartinR's answer [NSLog is unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993693/nslog-is-unavailable) , but something wrong, I can not add @objc in front of the method, need help.thanks.

[my codes...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCAeb.png)

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993693/nslog-is-unavailable.

Comment: @MartinR - If I understand correctly the OP wishes to call a Swift variadic function from Objective-C and your linked question does the reverse - call an Obj-C variadic from Swift. I don't know that it is possible to do what the OP is after, while you can declare a Swift function that takes a `va_list` value you cannot then pass that value to Swift's `NSLogv`, et al., as they take a `CVaListPointer`. Are you suggesting this is possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From @MartinR comment and reference to [NSLog is unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993693/nslog-is-unavailable) you know that Swift can call (Objective-)C functions & methods that take `va_list` arguments through the use of the Swift types `CVarArg` and `CVaListPointer`.

Many of the common (Objective-)C variadic functions & methods have a sibling which takes a `va_list`, so this support in Swift provides access to them.

> I also need to call this swift method in objective-c xxx.m file.

However you wish to go the other way, and having written a Swift variadic function version of your Objective-C method you found you couldn't call it. You attempted to ask what the solution was, [How do you call a Swift variadic method from Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53235608/how-do-you-call-a-swift-variadic-method-from-objective-c), the indirect answer (your question was marked as duplicate) to that question provides a hint – to use an array – but doesn't handle the generality you require for your formatted-print type scenario. Let's see if we can get there...

*(Using Xcode 10/Swift 4.2, any other version of Swift is probably different.)*

We'll use the following Swift class as basis:

```
class SwiftLog : NSObject
{
   // Swift entry point
   static func Log(_ format : String, args : CVarArg...)
   {
      withVaList(args) { LogV(format, $0)}
   }

   // Shared core
   private static func LogV(_ format : String, _ args: CVaListPointer)
   {
      NSLogv(format, args)
   }
}
```

This provides Swift with a variadic function which will take all the Swift library types you are probably interested in, and a few more you not (3287 are listed in [Apple's `CVarArg` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cvararg)). The private core function here is trivial, you probably wish to do something a little more involved.

Now you wish to call `Log()` from Objective-C but, as you've discovered, you cannot due to the `CVarArg`. However Objective-C can call Swift functions which take `NSObject` arguments, and `NSObject` implements `CVarArg`, which gets us to our first attempt:

```
   // Objective-C entry point
   @objc static func Log(_ format : String, args : [NSObject])
   {
      withVaList(args) { LogV(format, $0) }
   }
```

This works as-is but every argument must be an *object* and formatted with `%@`, switching to Objective-C:

```
[SwiftLog LogObjects:@"%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|%@" args:@[@"42", @4.2, @"hello", @31, @'c', NSDate.new]];
```

produces:

```
42|4.2|hello|31|99|Sun Nov 11 08:47:35 2018
```

It works within limits, we have lost the flexibility of formatting – no `%6.2f`, `%x` etc. – and the character has come out as `99`.

Can we improve it? If you are prepared to sacrifice the ability to print `NSNumber` values as is, then yes. Over in Swift change the `Log()` function to:

```
   @objc static func Log(_ format : String, args : [NSObject])
   {
      withVaList(args.map(toPrintfArg)) { LogV(format, $0) }
   }
```

Skipping `toPrintfArg` for the moment (its just large and ugly) over in Objective-C we can call this version as:

```
[SwiftLog Log:@"%@|%4.2f|%10s|%x|%c|%@" args:@[@"42", @4.2, @((intptr_t)"hello"), @31, @'c', NSDate.new]];
```

which produces:

```
42|4.20|     hello|1f|c|Sun Nov 11 08:47:35 2018
```

Much better, and the character is correct. So what does `toPrintfArg` do?

In the above we had to pass an array of *objects* to Swift, and to do that all the primitive values are wrapped as `NSNumber` objects.

In Objective-C an `NSNumber` object does not reveal much about what it wraps, the access methods (`.doubleValue`, `.integerValue` etc.) will *convert* whatever the wrapped value was into a value of the requested type and return it.

However `NSNumber` is "toll-free bridged" to the the Core Foundation types `CFBoolean` and `CFNumber`; the former of these is for booleans (obviously!) and the latter for all the other numeric types and, unlike `NSNumber`, provides a function that returns the type of the wrapped value so it can be unwrapped without conversion. Using this information we can extract the original *(experts, yes, see below)* values from the `NSNumber` objects, all those extracted value in Swift will all implement `CVarArg`, here goes:

```
   private static func toPrintfArg(_ item : NSObject) -> CVarArg
   {
      if let anumber = item as? NSNumber
      {
         if type(of:anumber) == CFBoolean.self { return anumber.boolValue }

         switch CFNumberGetType(anumber)
         {
            case CFNumberType.sInt8Type:     return anumber.int8Value
            case CFNumberType.sInt16Type:    return anumber.int16Value
            case CFNumberType.sInt32Type:    return anumber.int32Value
            case CFNumberType.sInt64Type:    return anumber.int64Value
            case CFNumberType.float32Type:   return Float32(anumber.floatValue)
            case CFNumberType.float64Type:   return Float64(anumber.doubleValue)
            case CFNumberType.charType:      return CChar(anumber.int8Value)
            case CFNumberType.shortType:     return CShort(anumber.int16Value)
            case CFNumberType.intType:       return CInt(anumber.int32Value)
            case CFNumberType.longType:      return CLong(anumber.int64Value)
            case CFNumberType.longLongType:  return CLongLong(anumber.int64Value)
            case CFNumberType.floatType:     return anumber.floatValue
            case CFNumberType.doubleType:    return anumber.doubleValue
            case CFNumberType.cfIndexType:   return CFIndex(anumber.int64Value)
            case CFNumberType.nsIntegerType: return NSInteger(anumber.int64Value)
            case CFNumberType.cgFloatType:   return CGFloat(anumber.doubleValue)
         }
      }

      return item;
   }
```

This function will unwrap *(experts, yes, most, see below)* `NSNumber` objects to the original value type while leaving all other objects as is to be formatted by `%@` (as shown by the `NSString` and `NSDate` objects in the example).

Hope that helps, at least more than it confuses! Notes for the curious/experts follow.

---

**Notes & Caveats**

*Preserving C Pointers*

In the above example the C string `"hello"` was passed by converting it to `intptr_t`, a C integer type the same size as a pointer, rather than as a pointer value. In this context this is fine, a `va_list` is essentially an *untyped* bob of bytes and the format tells `NSLogv()` what type to interpret the next bytes as, converting to `intptr_t` keeps the same bytes/bits and allows the pointer to be wrapped as an `NSNumber`.

However if you application needs to have an actual pointer on the Swift side you can instead wrap the C string as an `NSValue`:

```
[NSValue valueWithPointer:"hello"]
```

and unwrap it in `toPrintfArg` by adding:

```
      if let ptr = (item as? NSValue)?.pointerValue
      {
         return ptr.bindMemory(to: Int8.self, capacity: 1)
      }
```

This produces a value of type `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>`, which implements `CVarArg` (and as the latter the `capacity` is irrelevant).

*Do You Always Get The Same Type Back?*

If you wrap a C type as an `NSNumber` and then unwrap it as above, could the type change due to *argument promotion* (which means that integer types smaller than `int` get passed as `int` values, `float` values as `double`) in C? The answer is *maybe* but the required type for the `CVarArg` value is the promoted type so it should not make any difference *in this context* – the type of the unwrapped value with suit the expected format specifier.

*What about `NSDecimalNumber`?*

Well spotted, if you try to print an `NSDecimalNumber`, which is a subclass of `NSNumber`, the above `toPrintfArg` will unpack it as a `double` and you must use a floating-point format and not `%@`. Handling this is left as an exercise.

Comment: I just have one more question: how to use Objective-C macro if I used swift language `#define NSLog(fmt, ...) [SwiftLog method]`    @CRD THANKS!