# How do you call a Swift variadic method from Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift

How do you call a Swift variadic method from Objective-C?

```
class func printLog(msgToPrint: String, _ args: CVarArg...) -> Void
{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift methods with variadic parameters cannot be called from Objective-C.